# In general, will the ILP be solved faster if the number of variables is smaller?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, linear-programming, discrete-optimization, integer-programming

This question might be a little bit vague. Suppose I have a variable $x$ in an ILP formulation such that $x$ can choose $\{0,1,2,3,4\}$. Now I use four binary variables to replace $x$, ($x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4$ to replace $x$). Will the new ILP be solved slower than the original one because we have more variables?

In general, is there any relationship between the speed of solving ILP and the number of variables or the number of constraints?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general of course the more variables and constraints - the bigger the program - the slower it will be to solve. But I would not expect any straightforward, easily reversible transformations to cause a massive slowdown in solving, for two reasons:

1. The speed of solving also depends on something intangible about the structure of the ILP, and this is harder to change than it looks;
2. ILP solvers vary, but they are pretty smart. So for example if you replaced an unrestricted ($\mathbb R$-valued) variable $x$ by the difference of two nonnegative variables $y-z$, I think it wouldn't make much of a difference because the solver is capable of doing such things on its own.

Specifically, in a replacement like changing a variable $x \in \{0,1,2,3,4\}$ into a sum $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4$ where $x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4 \in \{0,1\}$, I would not worry from harsh consequences due to the number of variables. I *would* worry about a potential slowdown for a different reason: the new ILP has many symmetric and identical-looking solutions that are often hard to deal with. (For example, $x=2$ can be represented as $(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4) = (1,1,0,0)$ or as $(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4) = (0,1,0,1)$ or in four other ways.) So, I suspect adding a symmetry-breaking inequality like $x_1 \le x_2 \le x_3 \le x_4$ would help a lot - especially if you are doing this many times, or with a variable with a bigger range than $0$ to $4$.

At that point, I don't expect a major difference between the formulation with $x$ and the formulation with $x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4$, though it probably depends on the specific ILP solver and the approach taken. (Branch-and-bound-based algorithms might not even notice, but certain cutting plane algorithms might be happier working with one or the other.)

Comment: It is really helpful, especially the symmetry thing which I didn't think about. I have a follow-up question, will the increase of the feasible region of a variable also slow ILP in general? In many cases, we actually have a trade-off between fewer variables but larger feasible regions and more variables but smaller feasible regions, which one do you think would be better in general?

Comment: I think a short answer is that with ILPs, there's no "in general". Try both, especially if you can try both on a small version of the problem and extrapolate. I don't think that having a bigger feasible region is a problem by itself, but one formulation may be worse than the other for reasons you did not think of.